# Split single column in multiple row and then format the data

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I need some help
I have data in below format in a single column:

```
A:1   
B:2   

A:3   
C:8   
B:2   

C:4   
B:2
```

Need an output in below format:

```
A,B,C
1,2,
3,2,8
,2,4
```

Kindly suggest!!

Comment: You have tagged it with Awk, looks like the appropriate tool. Can you share what you have already tried and how did it fail?

Comment: ... or [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html), specifying `xtab` with `:` as pair separator and `csvlite` as the respective input and output formats

Comment: your datas are already an separated list you can just read it from its current form. You do not need to modify or sort them. If so please edit question with real use-case and your real data set .

Answer (score 2):

With a sufficiently recent version of [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
$ ~/src/miller/c/mlr --ixtab --ips ':' --ocsvlite clean-whitespace then unsparsify yourfile
A,B,C
1,2,
3,2,8
,2,4
```

If your data does not have trailing whitespace, you can omit the `clean-whitespace` in which case an older version of `mlr` will suffice. If you have a version without `clean-whitespace` but your data needs it, then you can combine it with a separate tool such as `sed`:

```
sed 's/ *$//' yourfile | mlr --ixtab --ips ':' --ocsvlite unsparsify
```